# PyGame Timer doesn't release events at expected rate

Tags: python, pygame

I am using `pygame.time.set_timer(event,milliseconds)` to add 2 USEREVENTs onto the queue; USEREVENT+1 every second (1000ms), and USEREVENT every 5ms. This SHOULD mean that I get 200 USEREVENT's for every USEREVENT+1 I get. I only get 100 events.

It seems that 10ms is the smallest delay the timer can have. I'm trying to use this to control my FPS, and the USEREVENT+1 signals to "update" the game logic by a tick, but if the timer has a lower cap of 10ms, then that means I can't go higher than 100fps. Does anyone know why?

Also, for bonus points, milliseconds must be an integer, which means I can only have an fps that is a multiple of 1000 (such as 10, 20, 25, 50, 100). How do you think I could achieve, say, 60fps with this method? Originally, I was sleeping until it's time for the next frame, but I want it to be nice to the CPU so I want idling in between ticks instead. This is why I'm using pygame.time.set_timer, because pygame.event.wait idles until an event comes on the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For limiting FPS, use: `Clock.tick(fps_cap)`

> http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#Clock.tick
>   This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many
>   milliseconds have passed since the previous call.
>
> If you pass the optional framerate argument the function will delay to
>   keep the game running slower than the given ticks per second. This can
>   be used to help limit the runtime speed of a game. By calling
>   Clock.tick(40) once per frame, the program will never run at more than
>   40 frames per second.
>
> Note that this function uses SDL_Delay function which is not accurate
>   on every platform, but does not use much cpu. Use tick_busy_loop if
>   you want an accurate timer, and don't mind chewing cpu.

Comment: Sadly, I want TWO framerates- One for game ticks, one for refreshing.

However, I've gotten it all figured out (I decided to just stick with multiples of 1000 anyway, it looks smooth), so I'll give you the upvote as you are, technically, correct. :) Thanks!

Comment: In that case, you may be interested in this: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/ConstantGameSpeed?parent=CookBook Constant physics update, yet variable fps rate. And scheduling callbacks.